# Launch Jelly Bean Voice Search from an app?

Tags: android

How do I directly launch the default google voice search on jellybean after which you can directly speak without pressing any buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will send you to your default voice search application. Just use it as you would usually with an `onClickListener` for example

Comment: It will take me to the application but will it auto initiate voice search so that I can speak without pressing any other thing

Comment: Hmm it worked for me on my Galaxy S3 4.1.2.. What's your android version?